# How to auto play a song when Windows starts up

Tags: boot, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, music, winamp

I know how to play a song or run a program at the start-up.
Merely, putting the shortcut of the file into the Startup folder and that's okay.

Anyway, I would like it to play and not appear on the desktop.
I would like the user to not see it. How can I make that possible?
I have got WindowsMediaPlayer / VLC Media Player / Winamp.

In short, I would like to hide the player so that it doesn't appear when the file is being launched.

I have got
Windows 7 Ultimate
x64

Cheers,
Francis

Answer (score 2):

You can change the sound on startup by going to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound > Sounds Tab.

From there you can change the Windows Startup sound, but they have to be .Wav files.  There is programs out there to convert mp3s etc to .Wav files.

You can scroll down to Windows logon and change the sound file to any .Wav file you want by selecting browse..  This is in the program events box.

Comment: An old trick since windows XP is to rename an MP3 to wav and it still works. This allows you to use small files.

Answer (score -1):

just change ur song into wav format via any converter theb all u have to do create shortcut for your song and right click on the shortcut then in properties
down in Run > change it from (Normal Window) into (Minimized) then hit apply ok
and open run by pressing " windows Button + R " then Type 'shell:startup' it gonna take u to startup folder past ur song thier and again make sure from properies that ur song set as Run > Minimized and that is also programmes as same as song create shortcut for your application and right click properties then Run Minimized.
i hope it benefit u
kk